# After setting MapMode the map won't pan or zoom

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Based on a user preference, I'm setting the MapMode like this on the page_loaded event:

```
if (Singleton.Instance.appSettings.MapMode)
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.MapMode mode = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.AerialMode();
    this.map1.SetMode(mode, true);
}
else
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Core.MapMode mode = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.RoadMode();
    this.map1.SetMode(mode, true);
}
```

If I comment this condition, map pans and zooms perfectly. If I leave this condition on, the map changes mode accordingly, but won't pan or zoom (if I enable the zoombar it will zoom when I press the buttons but again, won't pan).

Any help appreciated ;)

Comment: Just fully repro'd this on my box as a 7.1 project.  Same result.  Tossed it at some product guys I know, wait and see....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured this out.

Do a

map1.Mode = mode;

instead of the map1.SetMode call.

SetMode appears to hang the pan/zoom.

Not sure why.  If I get any updates on the why I'll let you know.

But at least you know how to get around it.

Carpe phone!
Healy